# Issue with create index with mapping

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch.net

I'm using elastic search version 7.1.0 and NEST 6.7.0 with Elasticsearch.Net 6.7.0.
While I'm trying to create an index I've got an error.

This is my code, I was using the same code on NEST and Elasticsearch.Net version 6.4.0 and it was working fine

```
var result =   Client.CreateIndex(DefaultIndex, c => c
                .Settings(s => s
                    .NumberOfShards(numberOfShards)
                    .NumberOfReplicas(numberOfReplicas)
                    .BlocksReadOnly(false)
                )
                .Mappings(m => m
                    .Map<SearchDocument>(mm => mm
                        .AutoMap(3)
                    )
                )
            );
```

This is the error that I got

> Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on PUT:
>   /local_brainbank_index
>
> ## Audit trail of this API call:
>
> - [1] BadResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.2880040
>
>   ## OriginalException: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.. Call: Status
>
> code 400 from: PUT /local_brainbank_index. ServerError: Type:
>   mapper_parsing_exception Reason: "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root
>   mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [searchdocument :
>   {properties={sourceId={type=integer}, sourceType={type=text,
>   fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}},
>   authorName={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256,
>   type=keyword}}}, subject={type=text,
>   fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}},
>   imageURL={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256,
>   type=keyword}}}, id={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256,
>   type=keyword}}}, sourceName={type=text,
>   fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, body={type=text,
>   fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, uRL={type=text,
>   fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}}}]" CausedBy:
>   "Type: mapper_parsing_exception Reason: "Root mapping definition has
>   unsupported parameters:  [searchdocument :
>   {properties={sourceId={type=integer}, sourceType={type=text,
>   fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}},
>   authorName={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256,
>   type=keyword}}}, subject={type=text,
>   fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}},
>   imageURL={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256,
>   type=keyword}}}, id={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256,
>   type=keyword}}}, sourceName={type=text,
>   fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, body={type=text,
>   fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, uRL={type=text,
>   fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}}}]"" --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400)
>   Bad Request.    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   Elasticsearch.Net.HttpWebRequestConnection.Request[TResponse](RequestData
>   requestData)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

## Request:

```
{"mappings":{"searchdocument":{"properties":{"id":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"sourceType":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"sourceId":{"type":"integer"},"sourceName":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"authorName":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"subject":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"body":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"uRL":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}},"imageURL":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}}}}},"settings":{"index.number_of_replicas":0,"index.blocks.read_only":false,"index.number_of_shards":1}}
```

## Response:

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root
>   mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [searchdocument :
>   {properties={sourceId={type=integer}, sourceType={type=text,
>   fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}},
>   authorName={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256,
>   type=keyword}}}, subject={type=text,
>   fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}},
>   imageURL={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256,
>   type=keyword}}}, id={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256,
>   type=keyword}}}, sourceName={type=text,
>   fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, body={type=text,
>   fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, uRL={type=text,
>   fields={keyword={ignore_above=256,
>   type=keyword}}}}}]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed
>   to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported
>   parameters:  [searchdocument : {properties={sourceId={type=integer},
>   sourceType={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256,
>   type=keyword}}}, authorName={type=text,
>   fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}},
>   subject={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256,
>   type=keyword}}}, imageURL={type=text,
>   fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, id={type=text,
>   fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}},
>   sourceName={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256,
>   type=keyword}}}, body={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256,
>   type=keyword}}}, uRL={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256,
>   type=keyword}}}}}]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root
>   mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [searchdocument :
>   {properties={sourceId={type=integer}, sourceType={type=text,
>   fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}},
>   authorName={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256,
>   type=keyword}}}, subject={type=text,
>   fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}},
>   imageURL={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256,
>   type=keyword}}}, id={type=text, fields={keyword={ignore_above=256,
>   type=keyword}}}, sourceName={type=text,
>   fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, body={type=text,
>   fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}, uRL={type=text,
>   fields={keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}}}}]"}},"status":400}

Comment: Elasticsearch in version 7.x works best with NEST in version 7.x.

Comment: @Rob there is no 7.x version for NEST. The latest version is 6.7.0. which I'm using

Comment: There is, but in alpha. You need to check “ allow prereleases” checkbox(or dropdown) in nuget manager. https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFlp5.jpg

Comment: One line: Update your ElasticSearch.NET with the version number for your ElasticSearch installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NEST and Elasticsearch.Net 6.7.0 are not compatible with Elasticsearch 7.x. Please use NEST and Elasticsearch.Net 7.x, the latest of which to be released is [7.0.0-alpha2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST/7.0.0-alpha2) at this time.